# 2023 From Single Digits

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Using only the digits, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9, in that order, how can you make the number 2023 using the +, -, ✕ and ÷ operations? (You can use as many parentheses as you want)

Comment: There are two solutions, one has already been found.

Comment: Clue: $2023=7^2\times17$

Comment: I think you mean $2023=7*17^2$.

Comment: yes, right. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this one has been said yet:

> $(1 - 2 - 3*4 + 5*6)*7*(8 + 9)$

> No division needed here either!

Comment: Yes, very similar to the one by isaacg.

Comment: @RonnieChen agreed, yet somehow distinct!

Answer (score 19):

Using the fact that $7*17*17=2023$,

> $(1-2+3+4+5+6)*7*(8+9)$

> No division needed!

Answer (score 18):

Here is the answer with only using $+$, $\times$, and $\div$ without any parentheses and $-$;

> $1+2*3+4*567*8/9$

Comment: Sorry, you cannot combine digits to form a multi-digit number.

Comment: @RonnieChen in the question, you do not say you can use parentheses either :)

Comment: Actually, this is the most accurate answer given the question as it is written: digits are "pieces" of a number and parentheses aren't in the allowed symbol list. Great job!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a solution using all the operations and the digits in the same order.

> $((-(-1)/2)*3*4)+5+6)*(7*(8+9))$
>  [image]

Some proofs

> [image]
>  [image]

Solve path

> I looked for factors of 2023 and found 17 and 119. Looked for factors of 119 and found 7 amd 17. Tada, I can use 7,8,9 to get 119. Now, 17 is a prime number. No factors. So, a bit of trial and errors and we can easily use digits 1,2,3,4,5,6 to get 17. Idea was to use bigger digits 5,6 with additions/substractions and smaller ones for other operations.

Comment: That is correct, there is another solution

Answer (score -2):

There are a number of solutions, but the first one I came across was:

> (1 + 2 + 3) * 4 * 5 + 6 - 7 * (8 + 9)

Comment: this is equal to 7

Comment: Looks like `((1 + 2 + 3) * 4 * 5 + 6 - 7) * (8 + 9)` was actually meant.  Or `(1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 + 6 - 7) * (8 + 9)`, for fewer parentheses.

Comment: Evidence: `dc <<<'1 2 3 4 5 **** 6+ 7- 8 9+*p'`